# How can I wire this motor’ capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, motor, wiring

I am trying to repair this low viscosity fluid pump, I have the original start and run capacitors but do not know how they are wired. When I found the pump Z2 and U1 were connected between which confuses me on how to proceed with the rest of the connections. Also I am very unaware of the purpose of X3 male. I attach a photo of the state of the connections as when I found it, hope someone can help this ignorant fool. Documentation regarding circuitry is nowhere to be found, it is however a single phase 220 volt pump. Model number is: 2BV3151-0GW02-1E. More details in the respective datasheet:

http://www.compressor.fi/media/EsitePDF/2BV3_vacuum.pdf

Color coding is as follows:

- Z2 black
- U1 white
- Z1 green
- U2 pink
- N and L1 both red (unaware if correctly placed)

[image]

Comment: This is like saying "I have a red car with a pump. How do I wire it?" We have no idea which pump this could be. What is the pump make and model number? A full photo will help. 240VAC? Single-phase? Edit and attach a photo of the nameplate also if possible. We need a lot more info.

Comment: The best chance for making this work would be to see if you can figure out the brand and model and try to get documentation.  If that is unsuccessful, trace the circuitry on the board and try to figure out how it works. I assume it disconnects the start capacitor based on time or current. There is practically no chance of getting any specific advice based on the information provided.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, I have added the requested details, however with all due respect @rdtsc user I think it has nothing to do with a red car. As far as my little knowledge if electric motors goes, nearly all of them follow a repetitive pattern on capacitor (start and run) and coil wiring.

Comment: Robin I do have to agree With the other comments you say low viscosity pump but link to a vacuum pump,  single phase 220 is it 220 to ground or split phase it makes a difference The board in the pump is not normal for motors. That looks to be some kind of speed control off a Ferrari would be my guess for the red car type ok it could be a timer for the caps but we need to know what it came off of to be helpful (the car examples were to try and make a point) is there a number on the PC board